# Replace a column in a file but maintain the space format

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a code below that replaces the 4th column in fileA based on the data in fileB but the output didn't maintain the spaces of the original file. Is there anyway to do it?

```
 tr , " " <fileB | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} {$4=a[$4];print}' - fileA
```

fileA

```
 xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002
```

fileB

```
 3100,3000
 W0002,Z0002
```

output using the code above:

```
 xxx xxx xxx W0002
```

expected output:

```
xxx    xxx   xxx W0002
```

Comment: Can the last field occur eslewhere in the line ?If not you can use `a[$4]&&sub($4,a[$4])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {split($0,a,",");b[a[2]]=a[1];next} {n=split($0,d,/[^[:space:]]*/);if(b[$4])$4=b[$4];for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s",d[i],$i);print ""}' fileB fileA
```

It store the spaces in an array, so it can reuse it later

Example:

```
cat fileA
xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002   not change this
xxx   xxx  Z0002 zzz
xxx Z000223213 xxx Z0002 xxx xxx xxx Z0002
```

```
cat fileB
3100,3000
W0002,Z0002
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR {split($0,a,",");b[a[2]]=a[1];next} {n=split($0,d,/[^[:space:]]*/);if(b[$4])$4=b[$4];for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s",d[i],$i);print ""}' fileB fileA
xxx    xxx   xxx  W0002   not change this
xxx   xxx  Z0002 zzz
xxx Z000223213 xxx  W0002 xxx xxx xxx Z0002
```

---

Some more readable and how it works:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {                           # For the first file "fileB"
    split($0,a,",")                 # Split it to an array "a" using "," as separator 
    b[a[2]]=a[1]                    # Store the data in array "b" using second column as index
    next                            # Skip to next record
    }
    {                               # Then for the file "fileA"
    n=split($0,d,/[^[:space:]]*/)   # Split the spaces inn group and store them in array "d"
    if(b[$4])                       # If array "b" as data for field "4"
        $4=b[$4]                    # Change filed "4" to data found in array "b"
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)               # Loop trough all field in the line
        printf("%s%s",d[i],$i)      # print correct separator and data
    print ""                        # Add new line at the end
    }
' fileB fileA                       # Read the files.
```

Comment: This will fail if it occurs elsewhere on the line though, also this assignment `c=b[$NF]` seem unnecessary, and if there is no `b[$NF]` then you will replace the last field with nothing.

Comment: @JID updated to reflect column `4` and remove the temporary variable.

Comment: this will still fail if the pattern occurs before the fourth field, hence my comment on the questiion.

Comment: @JID Thanks for feedback.  It should be ok now, and also preserve other lines.  If I just use `b[$4]&&sub($4,b[$4])` it will remove lines that does not have data from `fileA`

Comment: Jotne, you have addressed most of the concerns! There is still one problem though, imagine the line was `xxx    Z000223213   xxx Z0002 xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002` the second field would be replaced instead of the fourth.Obviously i don't know whether this could occur and OP didn't reply to my question but you may want to note that it is an assumption :)

Comment: @JID I needed to go back to my old notes to find how to preserve space.  This is a more generic approach and should work.

Comment: yep that works now. NICE! Last thing, is that `4i++` a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

Use gsub (regular expression substitution), with white space pattern before it, and end of line `$` after it will solve the problem.

Test file:

```
$ cat fileA
xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002
xxx    xxx   Z0002 xxx
xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002YY
```

Command execute and results:

```
$ tr , " " <fileB | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}  a[$4]=="" {print} a[$4]!=""{gsub(" "$4"$", " "a[$4], $0);print}' - fileA
xxx    xxx   xxx W0002
xxx    xxx   Z0002 xxx
xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002YY
```

Comment: However, this assumes that the use of space as the separator,  not <TAB>.

Comment: I add some logic that, if the keyword is not found, `$4` will be left as is, i.e. won't got converted to empty string.

Comment: And has the same problems as jotnes answer if the pattern occurs before field 4, or even if the pattern contains meta characters that will be interpereted by awk. Try it with my input data

Comment: Don't you see my test file above? There is one line with pattern occurring before field 4.

Comment: Ya. Meta-character is a problem.

Comment: In my test, only meta-char in fileB raise problems.  meta-char in fileA seems OK.

Comment: Why this extra command `tr , " " <fileB`, when you can just use `split` within `awk`

Comment: @Jotne:  just lazy.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Long awk answer

This is a bit overkill for this question but i think it will be useful for others.

It will avoid problems with metacharacters and the pattern occuring elsewhere on the line.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {split($0,a,",");b[a[2]]=a[1];next}
     {
         while(match(substr($0,x+=(RSTART+RLENGTH-(x>1?1:0))),"[^[:space:]]+")){
             E[++D]=(RSTART+x-(x>1?1:0))
             F[D]=E[D]+RLENGTH
         }
     }

     b[$4]~/./{$0=substr($0,0,E[4]-1) b[$4] substr($0,F[4])}
     {x=1;D=0;delete E}1' FILEB FILEA
```

---

#### Example

**input**

*FILEA*

```
xxx    Z0002   xxx Z0002 xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002
xxx    Z0002   xxx dsasa xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002
```

*FILEB*

```
3100,3000
W0002,Z0002
```

**Output**

```
xxx    Z0002   xxx W0002 xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002
xxx    Z0002   xxx dsasa xxx    xxx   xxx Z0002
```

---

#### Explanation

Will add later